# libRInside.a an empty file

Tags: windows, qt, rinside

I'm trying to compile the qtdensity example from the RInside examples folder, using Qt, Windows 7, R 32bit.

I have followed all the instructions posted online on how to set up these tools since my ultimate goal is to develop a C++/R application in Qt.

When I try to build the project I get the following error:

E:\dev\R-2.15.2\library\RInside\lib\i386\libRInside.a:-1: error: file not recognized: File truncated

Indeed, the libRInside.a file is empty as well as the libRInside.dll file in the same folder.

I have installed, uninstalled, installed again the RInside package using the install.packages("RInside", type="source") command.

The same problem does not occur with the Rcpp package, installed the same way.

I would greatly appreciate any insights on this. I've recently started with C++ and as a result it has taken me a lot of effort to set up everything so far.

Thank you!
Laura

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did wrong but I solved it by copy-paste the same files from the archive available at the CRAN page of RInside